# This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page

Tags: javascript, android-studio, debugging, compiler-errors, failed-to-connect

the website is done using eclipse, after that deployed using AWS, now  im trying to convert it as an android studio. but after i connect a phone to the laptop i keep getting this error:

```
 This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
```

i have looked up in different solutions like this:
[LogCat output debugging help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234777/logcat-output-debugging-help)

and this:
[Setting a value in the debugger of a shared section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44462106/setting-a-value-in-the-debugger-of-a-shared-section)

but none of them related to my problem. 
any help could be appreciated